# HTML Hamburger menu pushes img down when activated

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

My hamburger menu pushes down my hero image when clicked, I have tried to add z-index or positions absolute and relative but it ruins the hamburger menu.

I am a beginner and I have been racking my brain for about 2 hours with this.

This started happening when I edited my max-width to be 1200px instead of 600px

```css
body {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  margin: 0px;
}


/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */

.topnav a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black;
  width: 32.8%;
  padding-top: 10px;
}


/* Changes color of links on hover */

.topnav a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}


/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */

.topnav a.active {
  color: #ffffff;
}


/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
  float: right;
}


/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    color: white;
  }
}


/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative
  }
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 82.5%;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 7.5%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Nav Bar and background -->
<div class="hero">
  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="#home" class="active">About Me</a>
    <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
    <a href="#about">Contact</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  &nbsp;
  <img src="IMG_8302.png" alt="Avatar">
  <div class="hero-text">
    <h1>Hey! I'm Zoe</h1>

    <p>I'm a Junior Web Developer</p>
    <p>Feel free to have a look around my website</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you include the HTML for a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: will do. whoops, must have done that by accident.

Comment: Can you include your javascript as well? What is your hero image in this case? The `hero` class is in your HTML but never defined in your CSS and your menu items are nested in it. Are you using an external library of some kind or is this all straight CSS/HTML/JS?